# Перевести время видео youtube?

Tags: java, android

Получил время видео youtube, через Json PT24M30S, можно как нибудить перевести, это время в секунды?

Comment: Умножить минуты на 60 и прибавить секунды?

Comment: Ну это я понял, как мне вытащить цифры с PT1H24M30S?

Comment: Если вопрос "как мне вытащить цифры с PT1H24M30S", то и надо спрашивать в "как мне вытащить цифры с PT1H24M30S", а не "как перевести в секунды".

Comment: Какое отношение к андроиду?

Comment: Можно через регулярные выражения, можно несколько раз через String.substring. и еще много вариантов.

Answer (score 3):

Вариантов масса. 
Например можно парсить строку руками, проще задом наперед, заводите три поля, для часов, минут, секунд, видите соответствующий символ в строке, значит перед ними цифры, считываете их, получаете число, записываете, типа такого:

```
static int timeStringtoSeconds(String time) {
    int h = 0;
    int m = 0;
    int s = 0;
    char currentModifier = 'S';
    String currentValue = "";
    for (int i = time.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(time.charAt(i))) {
            if (!currentValue.isEmpty()) {
                switch (currentModifier) {
                    case 'S':
                        s = Integer.parseInt(currentValue);
                        break;
                    case 'M':
                        m = Integer.parseInt(currentValue);
                        break;
                    case 'H':
                        h = Integer.parseInt(currentValue);
                        break;
                }
                currentValue = "";
            }
            currentModifier = time.charAt(i);
        } else {
            currentValue = time.charAt(i) + currentValue;
        }
    }
    return h * 60 * 60 + m * 60 + s;
}
```

Либо можно разбить на группы примерно регуляркой, и дальше просто уже из групп составлять значение, как-то так:

```
static int regex(String time){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("PT(\\d*H)?(\\d*M)?(\\d*S)?");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(time);
    int result = 0;
    if(m.find()){
        String hg = m.group(1);
        String mg = m.group(2);
        String sg = m.group(3);
        result += hg != null 
            ? Integer.parseInt(hg.substring(0, hg.length() - 1)) * 60 * 60 
            : 0;
        result += mg != null 
            ? Integer.parseInt(mg.substring(0, mg.length() - 1)) * 60 
            : 0;
        result += sg != null 
            ? Integer.parseInt(sg.substring(0, sg.length() - 1)) 
            : 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```